# Stuck with php foreach loop - need to run the loop with the same key once more

Tags: php, foreach, iterator

Well I'm stuck with this one.
I have a foreach loop nested in another foreach loop. Now on certain conditions I need to run the outer loop once again with the same key. 
While there is this function prev($array), which would set the iterator to the previous position, this does not seem to work and the php docs says

> As foreach relies on the >internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

The array I am working on is an associative array, so obviously I cannot easily switch to integer indexed iterations.

```
    $arrLocalCopy = $this->arrPrintOut;
    $groupCounter = 0; 
    foreach($this->arrPrintOut as $kOne => $rowA){
        //first and last row contain titles and totals, so we skip them
        if($groupCounter < 1 || $groupCounter == sizeof($this->arrPrintOut)-1  ){ $groupCounter++; continue; }
        $rowCounter = 0;
        foreach($arrLocalCopy as $k => $rowB){
            //skip rows that are "before" the outer loops row, as we want to compare only rows below the row we compare to.
            if ($rowCounter <= $groupCounter || $rowCounter == sizeof($arrLocalCopy)-1 ) { $rowCounter++; continue;  }

            //If those values are the same, then values belong to the same group and must be summed together.
            if($rowA['t']==$rowB['t'] && $rowA['y']==$rowB['y'] && $rowA['g']==$rowB['g'] && $rowA['q']==$rowB['q'])
            {
                //if values are the same, then data belongs to one group, lets group them together.
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['s'] += $rowB['s'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['b'] += $rowB['b'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['v'] += $rowB['v'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['r'] += $rowB['r'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['k'] += $rowB['k'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['n'] += $rowB['n'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['m'] += $rowB['m'];
                $this->arrPrintOut[$kOne]['l'] += $rowB['l'];
                unset($this->arrPrintOut[$k]); //row has been grouped to the current row, so we remove it from the array and from the copy.
                unset($arrLocalCopy[$k]);
                prev($this->arrPrintOut); //we need to run the outer loop with the same key again, as probably there is another row which could be grouped together with this row.
                $groupCounter--;
            }
            $rowCounter++;
        }
        $groupCounter++;
    }
```

Comment: Then use `for` loop, with `$key = key($array)` and `$value = $array[$key]`. So you can do `prev($array)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look in this direction. I assume you mean sth. like for($i...) { $key = key($array[$i]);...

Comment: yes, that's what I meant :-)

Comment: But what if the array is like $array = array(
    1    => "a",
    6  => "b",
); not $array = array(
    "1"    => "a",
    "6"  => "b",
); I mean how would it distinguish between array[6] and array[1]==second element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample.

`$rollback` is a variable to check if we `prev()` already

`$max` is the number of iterations. If you `prev()` you have to increment it.

```
<?php

$array = array(1 => "a", 6 => "b", 19 => "c");

$rollback=0;
$max = sizeof($array);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
        $key = key($array);
        $value = $array[$key];
        print "$key => $value\n";
        next($array);
        if ($value == "b" && $rollback == 0) {
                prev($array);
                $rollback = 1;
                $max++;

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so it's not what I wrote up there $key = key($array[$i]);, the trick is to use key($array) and move on with next etc. THANK YOU!